# Is there a global properties for cloudformation Resources section?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have a cloudformation template for my lambda:

```
Resources:
  Resource1:
    Type: AWS::Res
    Properties:
      StreamArn: 
         "Fn::Sub": "${var1}-${var2}"
  Resource2:
    Type: AWS::Res
    Properties:
      StreamArn: 
         "Fn::Sub": "${var1}-${var2}"
```

Is it possible to move these properties somewhere to `Properties` field of `Resources` section or any other place to avoid duplication?

```
Resources:
   Properties:
       StreamArn: 
           "Fn::Sub": "${var1}-${var2}"
```

I've tried to do it, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `Parameters` entry with a default value to create the equivalent to a Constant Variable, but it can't accept any values from the `Resources` section (since they haven't been created at that point).

Otherwise, no -- you'll need to duplicate the values. (As at the time of writing this answer.)

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `AWS::Serverless::Function`, you can use Globals section to have common properties in a stack in one place. So, you can put the resources you mentioned in a stack for them and define a Globals section that has `StreamArn`

See [docs](https://awslabs.github.io/serverless-application-model/globals.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SAM and the right resources then you can use the globals sections for this:

- AWS::Serverless::Function
- AWS::Serverless::Api, and
- AWS::Serverless::SimpleTable

> The Globals section is unique to AWS SAM. It defines properties that
>   are common to all your serverless functions and APIs. All the
>   AWS::Serverless::Function
>   AWS::Serverless::Api, and
>   AWS::Serverless::SimpleTable
>   resources inherit the properties that are
>   defined in the Globals section. For more information about the Globals
>   section, see Globals Section of the Template in the AWS Serverless
>   Application Model Developer Guide.

[Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-specification-template-anatomy-globals.html)

Answer (score 0):

The most convenient way that I found so far is to use mapping like:

```
Mappings:
  ParametersMap:
    Var1:
      Value: "A"
    Var2:
      Value: "B"
```

and then put line `!FindInMap: [ "ParametersMap", "Var1", "Value" ]` in all the places were you need `Var1` param